# sum numpy array of tags in one hot encoding

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that is a one hot encoding of all tags, like

```
[
 [
  [0,0,0]
  [1,0,0],
  [0,0,1]
 ],
 [
   [0,0,0],
   [0,0,0],
   [0,0,1],
 ]
]
```

I want to get this:

```
[
 [1,0,1],
 [0,0,1]
]
```

the arrays of tags are paded to same size ([0,0,0] means no tag)

How can I do that? I tryed many things but I'm a noob with python and numpy.

**EDIT**

I think this should works

```
[np.sum(x, axis=0) for x in array_tags]
```

but python(2.7) collapse if I run that. Any clue?

Comment: Simply sum along the second axis : `arr.sum(1)`?

Comment: I tryed `np.sum(tags_array, axis=0)` but python collapse (kill 9) and I have no idea why

Comment: What about `axis=1`?

Comment: @Divakar you should write up as a short answer...

Comment: @Aaron These are pretty basic stuffs. If that solved it, I would encourage OP to make a self-answered post.

Comment: axis=1 does not do what I want. Can I be getting out of memory? 4GB ram free + 4 swap. I hope no

Answer (score 0):

I found what I want on scikit-learn. I need to use `MultiLabelBinarizer`